# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from (9 errors)

Tags: php, soap, yii

In a section of the website, when I want to get one information about some month, at the 2 most recent months don't work, at the others months work properly. I get this error:

in /var/www/portal-transparencia/controllers/TransparenciaController.php at line 27

```
private function geraFolhaPagamento($mes, $ano) {
    // Lista dos servidores
    $servico = 'buscaservidores';
    $argumentos = array('N', '1');
    $arrayResultados = null;
    // Folha de pagamento
//    $servico = 'gerafichafinanceirapse';
//    $argumentos = array('07', '2016', '07', '2016', '0038', '1');         // Cliente soap
    $client = new SoapClient('http://cmcontagem.rps.com.br/cmcontagem/sgp/webservice/portal/wsdl');
    // Chamada
    $resultado = $client->__soapCall($servico, $argumentos);

    $textoResultado = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <buscaservidores>' . $resultado['dados'] . '</buscaservidores>';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 505; $i++) {
        $textoResultado = str_replace("<$i>", "<item id='$i'>", $textoResultado);
        $textoResultado = str_replace("</$i>", "</item>", $textoResultado);
```

The error its on line 27
       $client = new SoapClient('http://cmcontagem.rps.com.br/cmcontagem/sgp/webservice/portal/wsdl');

Comment: The error is not shown, you should try to add it in again.

Comment: my bad, im editing right now